# Is there an easy way to prompt the user for his preferred notification tone?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to create a notification that uses a different sound than Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND. Is there an easy way I can pop up a Sound picker where the user can choose from? and how do I use the sound picked for my notification?

Answer (score 0):

Like most things in Android, you can broadcast an intent. [example](http://www.ceveni.com/2009/07/ringtone-picker-in-android-with-intent.html).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER) is the full intent description in the Android docs.